# Serial Port not found by MATLAB to communicate with Arduino

Tags: arduino, serial, matlab

I'm just trying to know how to established serial communication between Arduino and MATLAB.  From this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymWXCPenNM4) I copied the code, but as for my  PC use "Windows" I had to change my serial port name. My arduino is connected to 'COM4' port . [image]

But When I run the code , error poped saying that : " Open failed: Port: COM4 is not available. No ports are available."
 I do not understand what this mean and how am I suppose to solve the problem. I have found nothing helpful in internet . Can you please help me out ?

[image]

my code is given below :

```
function [obj,flag]=setupSerial(comPort)

flag =1;
obj=serial(comPort);
set(obj,'DataBits',8);
set(obj,'StopBits',1);
set(obj,'BaudRate',9600);
set(obj,'Parity','none');
fopen(obj);
a='b';
while (a~='a')
   a=fread(obj,1,'uchar');
end
if(a=='a')
   disp('Serial Setup Complete');
end
  fprintf(obj,'%c','a');
  mbox = msgbox('Serial Communication setup'); uiwait(mbox);
  fscanf(obj,'%u');
  fclose(obj);
end
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You might not have closed it before.  I would suggest making the serial object global so you can close it even if you lose the local handle.

Comment: Probably a better fit for SuperUser since this is a PC hardware/software question.

Comment: I closed it , even I add this new line at the end to close it , still same problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your port may be used or open for another channel . Insert this line before creating the obj:

```
delete(instrfind({'port'},{comPort}));
```

This line will delete any previous setup of the comPort .